# Compute how many ways to get to (n,n) from (0,0) you must cross x=y only once at (k,k+1)

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

In the question we have a cat in $(0,0)$. The cat can only go right or up. The cat wants to reach $(n,n)$, but must go through one of the points above $(x=y)$. Meaning a point $(k,k+1)$. Compute how many different ways can the cat reach (n,n)?

I realized I need to denote a step to the right by $0$ and a step up by $1$ and sum the valid sequences though I'm not sure how to do this.

A solution would be very appreciated!

Comment: Do you know how to count it if there were no special condition ?

Comment: @trueblueanil I understand that the total paths to $(n,n)$ is ${2n \choose n}$, but how do I subtract all the "bad" paths from the total? how do I even look at them?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Look up Catalan numbers (paths that never *cross* the diagonal)

You already know how to compute total paths.

What further do you need to do ?

Comment: Has the hint been of no use  to you ?